# PHP fatal error: " Class '...' not found in ... on line

Tags: class, pdo, classnotfoundexception

i'm trying to build an API for school project,
i think i have everything right, but for some reason, the code doesn't read the use lines.

```
use repository\PDOPersonRepository;
use repository\PDOEventRepository;
use view\PersonJsonView;
use view\EventJsonView;
use controller\PersonController;

$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'wp1';
$pdo = null;

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=wp1",
    $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
    PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$personPDORepository = new PDOPersonRepository($pdo);
$personJsonView = new PersonJsonView();
$personController = new PersonController($personPDORepository, $personJsonView);
$eventPDORepository = new PDOEventRepository($pdo);
$eventJSonView = new EventJsonView();
$eventController = new EventJsonView($eventJSonView, $eventPDORepository);

Fatal error: Class 'repository\PDOPersonRepository' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Werkpakket1\app.php on line 22
```

phpstorm doesn't give errors in the code, so i don't really understand why it does that

Comment: So what autoloading mechanism are you using ...?

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined those classes in the file. You need to include some sort of autoloading mechanism or at least include the files where the classes are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` lines include classes based on their [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) rather than their physical location. It is different from `include` or `require`. If the `use` keyword is to find the classes, the code of those classes has to be included first.

Another approach is to use a custom [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which could match namespaces with the directories of the classes, so that they are loaded automagically only when you need (`use`) them.

In other words, your code above needs to be prepended with something like:

```
inculde 'Person.php';
```

Where that file would contain something like:

```
namespace repository;
class PDOPersonRepository { ... }
```

You could use multiple namespaces in a single file, but that is not common practice.

Comment: how do i do this properly? when i do "include 'repository\PDOPersonRepository' it says it that path is not found

Comment: Well... [PHP expects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that you use the `include` command to tell it where another code file can be found. It's up to you to create the file with some code in it, and have PHP read it. Basic understanding of the filesystem would help (fun intended).